# Rails custom.css.scss changes not showing up when I push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Locally my CSS changes work fine but when I push to Heroku I don't see the changes - and when I inspect element and look in application.css I can't find the class names I have created, so I don't think they are getting pushed to Heroku for some reason.

I have run rake db:migrate, restarted Heroku and basically everything else I can think of - to no avail.

If you care to have a look, I'm attempting to make modifications to http://theplayr.com - on the bottom the pagination CSS does not look like that locally. I have hidden 'previous' and 'next' when they aren't a clickable and aligned the pagination right with the following CSS:

```
.next_page.disabled {
display:none;
}
.previous_page.disabled {
    display:none;
}
.pager{
text-align:right;
}
```

Locally it works, on the live site it doesn't after I push to Heroku.

Comment: I had never had to do this before, but I guess I had not. I ran $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile and it fixed the problem. Thanks! =)

Comment: Do you know why I never had to do this before and why everytime I have to precompile now? It's quite annoying having to do this and for weeks it worked fine without doing it.

Comment: what version of rails you were using before ?

Comment: 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3. I did have a problem where a contractor added a file that made my local environment run Ruby 1.9.2 with a special gemset and I kept having to re-install Rails and bundler and other things. Maybe this was related? I got rid of that file and I always use 1.9.3 again. Is there something I can run where it gets precompiled automatically again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should precompile your assets `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`